# Как получить сокет?

Tags: веб-программирование, websocket

В общем, открыл консоль и ввёл Websocket, но он мне вернул native code.

Как получить данные, которые находятся в сокетах? Пробовал через DevTools, но он мне даже страницу не показывает. Хочу получить данные из телеграмм

Comment: В сокете нет данных, сокет это среда передачи. Сейчас вы фактически взяли в руки кусок трубы, никуда не подключенный и ожидаете, что из него потечет вода. Так вот трубу (сокет) сначала надо куда то подключить, где есть то, что по ней потечет. И в случае с сокетами часто надо еще и запросить что то конкретное. Читайте документацию на применение сокетов в конкретном случае

Comment: Логично! А то, что ты когда входишь то у тебя вызывается событие connection, вас это не смущает? Вы говорите, в нём нет данных? Увы, ошибаетесь. Он массив возвращает, как-бы

Comment: нет, совершенно не смущает. воды в куске трубы нет, пока ее к чему то не подключили. Когда подключили возникает событие connection и после начинает течь вода, в том случае если то к чему подключили эту трубу сразу эту воду передает. Все зависит от того куда именно вы подключаете сокет. Одни сервера сразу же шлют данные, а другие будут просто молчать и ничего не посылать пока вы явно их не попросите. Если сразу видите массив - значит сервер к которому вы подключились сразу его прислал. Но подключиться в начале все равно надо, а не просто написать "труба"

Comment: Такой кринж вы несёте, просто ору. При отправке сообщения, отправляется сокет, тоже щас это будешь писать? Перестань чушь нести.

Comment: Сокет не отправляется, отправляются данные через сокет. Сокет это средство связи. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)

Comment: та я вчера видел видос, как чел в консоль отправил команду сокет и он выдал ему массив с данными. Хорошо! Как я тогда могу получить массив этот?